# Java: Dividing pairs from an Array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, exception, divide

I am working on a project and am stuck on what to do next. I need to write a Java program that accepts from a user ten values and place those numbers in an array. The numbers in the array will be added together and the result displayed to the user. (I got that part)

Here is the problem: The program should compare the values for elements 1 and 2 (in the array) and divide the larger number by the smaller number. It should compare the values for all odd/even elements and divide the larger by the smaller value.

I do not know how to do this at all. I started with if-else statements but I am getting errors. It know it's a mess right now, but any help with dividing the array pairs would be very helpful. Send me links too, I have been unsuccessful finding any, so I can learn more.

Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

/import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExceptionHandler {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments10
 * 10
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter ten values:");
    System.out.println();
// Input the data from the user.

    int[ ] digit = new int[11];
    int sum = 0;
    //Declare an array

    for (int i = 1; i < digit.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Value " + i + ": ");
        digit[i] = in.nextInt();
        sum += digit[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Total Values in Array:"+ sum);
     // Calculate the sum and print the total

    System.out.println("Would you like to divide values?");
    // Fix this later


             int result= digit[i]; 
             if (digit[i] > digit[i + 1]) 
                 result = digit[i] / digit[i + 1]; 
             else {
                 (digit[i + 1] / digit[i]);
                }
    // Compare element 0 with 1, divide larger element by smaller element
             if (digit[i])> digit[i + 3])
                result = digit[i] / digit[ i+ 3];
             else{
                 (digit[i +3])/ digit[i];   
                 }

        }
```

Comment: do you mean compare 1st and 2nd value, and then 3rd and 4th value, and so on?

Comment: yes. I compare value 1 and 2, find out which one is bigger, then divide the smaller number by the larger one. Somewhere in there I also have to figure out which is odd and even...?

Comment: Check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25414276/2593269) below. you can use i for odd, and i+1 for even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using int for the division. Use a double instead, as it can divide two integers with decimal point precision.

```
// needed for division
double[] digit = new double[11];
for (int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++)
{
    digit[i] = (double)in.nextInt;
    sum += (int)digit[i];
}

//you can use this variable if needed, if not, ignore it
double[] divisionResult = new double[digit.length / 2];
for(int i = 1; i < digit.length; i += 2) {
    double result = digit[i]; 
    if (result > digit[i + 1]) 
       result = result / digit[i + 1]; 
    else {
       result = digit[i + 1] / result;
    }
    divisionResult[i / 2] = result;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

EDIT: I'm also not sure why you're using

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
```

Because you used that, I used it similarly above, but the actual convention should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Doesn't make a huge difference, but better to follow good coding conventions :)

Comment: +1 for realising the integer division, so far the first who noticed. :D Although there is still something missing (make ``digit`` a ``double[]``)

Comment: Still the only thing that matters is that the array **must** be of type ``double[]``, regardless whether integer numbers or rational numbers are divided.

Comment: @NVBhargava this code won't work. The digit[i] / digit[i + 1] will still truncate, but will store that truncated value in the double. I will edit the code to fix it. Feel free to roll it bock if you want.

Comment: @nmore, I agree, that is the reason why @ThreeFx was suggesting for `double[] digit;` But sure, go ahead!

Comment: I made it 11 instead of 10 because when the Values are displayed I don't want it to display Value 0, I wanted it to start at 1.

Comment: As long as this helped you :) If it did, please mark it as answer.

Comment: @NVBhargava thank you so much for the help. My code looks beautiful. I thought about using double in the first place, but your suggestion makes everything look so much cleaner. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `for` loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
     if (digit[i] > digit[i + 1]) {
        result = digit[i] / digit[i + 1];
     }
     else {
        result = digit[i + 1] / digit[i];
     }
     System.out.println(result);
  }
```

Comment: I have to include an exception in case someone puts in a zero or NaN. I will do that later.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I got it right what you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i = i+2) {
    int firstDigit = array[i];
    int secondDigit = array[i+1];
    if (firstDigit > secondDigit) {
        return firstDigit / secondDigit;
    } else {
        return secondDigit / firstDigit;
    }
}
```

You iterate over the array and compare the first with the second element. By increasing your counterVariable (i) by two you always compare the 1st / 2nd, 3rd / 4th and so on numbers of the array.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You variable `i` is local to the for loop in your code. If you want to use i again, you need to declare it outside of the loop to for you to use it outside the scope of the for loop. In addition, the last value of "i" here is the last array index, which would throw on array out of bound exception anyway (in other words you need to make another loop where you initialize "i" to 0 again under your "Would you like to divide values?" statement). Lastly, you need to do an assignment, so

```
(digit[i + 1] / digit[i]);
```

is not a valid statement. If you want to write it into result, you need to write:

```
result = (digit[i + 1] / digit[i]);
```

and if you want to override in place you can use

```
digit[i+1] = (digit[i + 1] / digit[i]);
```

or

```
digit[i + 1] /= digit[i];
```